# Stack Overflow Teams: This email is already in use

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, login

I recently joined a Stack Overflow for Teams instance for my company. When I attempt to log in to it, it says:

> To confirm access to [company instance], we need to verify that you
>   have an @[company].com email address.

When I do that, it tells me:

> This email is already in use.

And I can't go any further?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have two Stack Overflow accounts that need to be merged. Please submit a [support ticket](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/tickets/new) and we can merge your accounts for you.